# what is the inverse of set?

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I was trying to jump around documents on line, and i see the `set` function for when i do `set("myString", "hello");` or `set("myMap.test", "world");` but i was curious as to what the inverse is?  I figured `unset` but when looking online at the Properties sections of Polymer 1.0 Dart code, i wasnt quite getting the information I wanted.

What is the inverse of set, to remove an attribute?  My particular use case is to remove a key from a map, `unset("myMap.testKey");`

Since `set` is defined in Polymer_base.dart, i thought it would rest somewhere within that file, but i did not see any "unset" or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it works but I would remove the element from the map and then call

```
notifyPath('myMap.testKey, null);
```

If the values was `null` already then this probably won't work.

Comment: the issue is that I have a computed property which checks for the number of keys in a maintenance map > 0, so ideally if there are no keys, it is ready to go.  As the key is resolved, it will remove itself from the map.  Even if i define it as undefined the key would be in the map still in this case, no?

Comment: Seems to be a valid way. See my updated answer. Otherwise just use `delete` and `set("myMap.test", undefined)` to get rid of the property and notify Polymer about it. If that causes issues you can try `notifyPath(path, value)` instead of `set(...)` (after `delete`).

Comment: undefined is a javascript thing, I am writing this in Dart, so perhaps it would just be null?  The downside is that even though setting it to undefined, it says it would loop over it still as it is in the map... So that being said maybe my approach of `isEnabled => myMap.length == 0;` is not the desired approach

Comment: I see. I didn't notice because it doesn't have the `dart` tag.

Comment: Oh, I wasnt sure if it needed the dart tag, as much as the dartPolymer tag... but thank you. :)

Comment: I would always add the `dart` tag if it is Dart related. More people monitor `dart` than `dart-polymer`.